# When I run the following code only even numbered lines are displayed. Can someone explain why is it so

Tags: python

```py
f=open(r"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\pqr.txt","r")
for line in f:
    print(f.readline())
f.close()
```

Comment: The for-loop reads a line in each iteration and "readline()" reads also a line.

Comment: @micheal I am new to python would please be willing to explain further and also suggest a workaround maybe

Comment: `line` is the next line in your file. Change `print(f.readline())` to `print(line)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 f=open(r"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\pqr.txt","r")
 for line in f:  #reads the first line upto the eof
          print(f.readline()) #reads the immediate next line upto eof
  f.close()
```

whats happening is the for loop with every iteration read a line until the `EOF`, when the code processed and comes across the `readline()` function it reads the new line. Thus only even number of lines are displayed.
The simplified logic is to print the line which reads each `obj` per iteration

```
f=open(r"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\pqr.txt","r") 
for line in f:
   print(line) 
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
f=open(r"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\pqr.txt","r") 
for line in f: 
     print(line) 
f.close()
```

In your code, `for` loop reads a line from `f` in `line` variable, which is ignored!
Then, another line is read with `f.readline()`, and this one is actually displayed.

### Update

Actually, in each iteration, th e `for` loop reads two lines:

- The first one is stored in `line`. The part of the code responsible of that is `line in f`.
- The second one is given to the function `print`. The part of the code responsible of that is `f.readline()`

Comment: @ThunderPhoenix a follow-up, can you explain why this happens? In my limited knowledge what should have happened was well the line should have run from 1 to the 'n' number of lines in the function and displayed each line